# Why ESM slower than CJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two code

One is:

**1. a.mjs(ESM)**

```
function Worker(health) {
  this._health = health ?? 10;
}

function JuniorEngineer(health, intelligence) {
  this._super(health);
  this._intelligence = intelligence ?? 1;
  this._isBornGenius = intelligence > 10;
}

Worker.prototype.work = function () {
  this._health--;
};

Worker.prototype.getHealth = function () {
  return this._health;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype = Object.create(Worker.prototype, {});

JuniorEngineer.prototype._super = function (health) {
  return Worker.call(this, health);
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.getIntelligence = function () {
  return this._intelligence;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.work = function () {
  Worker.prototype.work.call(this);
  this._intelligence++;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.isBornGenius = function () {
  return this._isBornGenius;
};

function main() {
  var startTime = performance.now();
  console.time();
  const amount = 10000000;
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    const junior = new JuniorEngineer(10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
    // %DebugPrint(junior);
    junior._isBornGenius;
  }
  var endTime = performance.now();
  console.timeEnd();

  // console.log(endTime - startTime);
}

main();

export { Worker, JuniorEngineer };
```

And another is:
**2. a.js(CJS)**

```
function Worker(health) {
  this._health = health ?? 10;
}

function JuniorEngineer(health, intelligence) {
  this._super(health);
  this._intelligence = intelligence ?? 1;
  this._isBornGenius = intelligence > 10;
}

Worker.prototype.work = function () {
  this._health--;
};

Worker.prototype.getHealth = function () {
  return this._health;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype = Object.create(Worker.prototype, {});

JuniorEngineer.prototype._super = function (health) {
  return Worker.call(this, health);
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.getIntelligence = function () {
  return this._intelligence;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.work = function () {
  Worker.prototype.work.call(this);
  this._intelligence++;
};

JuniorEngineer.prototype.isBornGenius = function () {
  return this._isBornGenius;
};

function main() {
  var startTime = performance.now();
  console.time();
  const amount = 10000000;
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    new JuniorEngineer(10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)).isBornGenius();
  }
  var endTime = performance.now();
  console.timeEnd();

  // console.log(endTime - startTime);
}

main();

module.exports = { Worker, JuniorEngineer };
```

when i run two file with command `node a.js` and `node a.mjs` and result is:
**ESM**
`145.3415`

**CJS**
`59.676541`

Why this is happen? Actually i think is not a loading mechanism's problem. When i measure average time of create instance, CJS more faster than ESM when create instance. How this can be happen?

I asked to gpt but i can't get reasonable answer....

Comment: the difference is not as stark if the code is identical 1.4X vs 2.4X with your different code ... which it isn't (

Comment: One of these is calling the `isBornGenius()` function, the other is accessing `_isBornGenius`. That's not the same thing.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, once the code is the same it does still seem to be 2.4X speed

Comment: yeah... code is not same. That is my mistake. But that is not matter... I fix it to make same code. But still same result.